# Jenkins with ZAP log in

Tags: jenkins, zap

i have question about ZAP Plugin,

my question is how to config build with my parameters, how to config jenkins parameters, without selenium test,

My parameters is, (windows)

1. Start ZAP
2. Start my localhost
3. Log in into my web application
4. Start scan

Thanks for fast answer.

And last question is how to config build when SELENIUM TEST is running during ZAP is attack.

Thanks a lot and plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I need windows batch command for start firefox, zap and start zap scanner

with parameters authentication login screen

Answer (score 0):

You need create a Java scenario and run via ZAP Proxy.

**Java sample** (sample come from [NoraUI POC](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi-POC))**:**

```
/**
 * NoraUi is licensed under the license GNU AFFERO GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
 * 
 * @author Nicolas HALLOUIN
 * @author Stéphane GRILLON
 */
package com.github.noraui.bot;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.github.noraui.utils.Utilities.OperatingSystem;
import com.github.noraui.utils.Utilities.SystemArchitecture;

public class FirstSimpleBotWithZAPProxy {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirstSimpleBotWithZAPProxy.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setAutodetect(false);
        proxy.setHttpProxy("http://localhost:8092");

        final OperatingSystem currentOperatingSystem = OperatingSystem.getCurrentOperatingSystem();
        String pathWebdriver = String.format("src/test/resources/drivers/%s/googlechrome/%s/chromedriver%s", currentOperatingSystem.getOperatingSystemDir(),
                SystemArchitecture.getCurrentSystemArchitecture().getSystemArchitectureName(), currentOperatingSystem.getSuffixBinary());

        if (!new File(pathWebdriver).setExecutable(true)) {
            logger.error("ERROR when change setExecutable on " + pathWebdriver);
        }

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathWebdriver);
        final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setProxy(proxy);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            driver.get("http://www.google.com/ncr");
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
            element.sendKeys("NoraUi");
            element.submit();
            logger.info(driver.getTitle());
            WebElement r = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='resultStats']"));
            logger.info(r.getText());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**ZAP result**:

[image]